# Relating PAGEID to sectionid-PageID in hyperlink

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

We have many pages which have link to other OneNote Pages. Section-ID and Page ID in the hyper link is different from the paged returned by the URL.

Example: For Page-ID: 1-422f7679a4e647f29bf990e2d7011caa!1-7028fe47-2ab9-4568-b5f9-fdc5f035eed1  section-Id is ={0590BF60-B259-42F5-9B1C-E21C7C3FE16D} in URL and page-id is {BAF4533A-381F-476E-A194-8397347952C2}

How do we convert 1-422f7679a4e647f29bf990e2d7011caa to 0590BF60-B259-42F5-9B1C-E21C7C3FE16D and 0590BF60-B259-42F5-9B1C-E21C7C3FE16D to BAF4533A-381F-476E-A194-8397347952C2

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:
[Any way in OneNote API to extract link to another OneNote page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207073/any-way-in-onenote-api-to-extract-link-to-another-onenote-page/36207449#36207449)

Id's in URLs and in the API are different.

For pages: You can relate them by extracting the page id from the oneNoteClientUrl property in the GET ~/pages API.

For sections: The GET ~/sections API does not return oneNoteClientUrls, but you can use the GET ~/pages API to get the parentSection.Id of a page, and the oneNoteClientUrl property of the page to retrieve the section id.