# How do MS-graph OneNote page IDs map to OneNote app link page IDs?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

In the MS Graph API the page IDs are in a form like this:

> `0-27696e96063a344f89a7735214aaa999!1-A0AC2C4AD3AAA999!34000`

The second part is the MS Graph section ID.

However OneNote page links (e.g. online, or copied from the app) use UUIDs as page IDs.

How can I get the MS Graph ID from the UUID - is there some mapping?  The use case is to grab a page ID from the OneNote app then immediately fetch that page from the MS Graph.

Alternatively, if there is some MS Graph query method that lets me pass information I can get from the OneNote app (e.g. Page and Section UUID) that would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was posed (and answered) by Velojet and Jorge Aguirre [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207073/any-way-in-onenote-api-to-extract-link-to-another-onenote-page)

Basically if you get the url of a personal OneNote page 
 `https://onedrive.live.com/...|<page-id>/)` 
 Then use this approach in the MS Graph query method

```
GET ~/pages?$filter=contains(links/oneNoteClientUrl/href,'<page-id>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The actual filter clause ends up looking like this: `contains(links/oneNoteClientUrl/href,'27EF70A5-DCBA-4640-BF63-B33AFDD9B7E9')`